# can´t make Regex work in React calculator

Tags: reactjs

I keep trying to make this Regex work for format inputting in my React calculator (which should limit operations and operators to valid mathematical formats. For instance, 1++++1 should not be allowed and should get replaced to 1+1, 12*+-3 should get replaced to 12-3, etc). The regex is as following: /^\d*([/+-/*=]\d+)*$/gi.
I can´t make it work, not matter how hard I try. I keep getting an "escape sequence" error.

Calculator:

```
class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value:""}
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
  handleClick(evt){
 const id=evt.target.id;
 const result= evt.target.value;

this.setState(prevState => ({
  value: `${prevState.value}${result}`.replace(/^0+\B/, "")
}));

if(id==="equals"){
    this.setState({value: math.eval(this.state.value)})
}
else if(id==="clear"){
this.setState({value : 0})  
 }

}



render() {
    return(
            <div id="container">
                <Display value={this.state.value} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="zero" value={'0'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="one" value={'1'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="two" value={'2'}/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="three" value={'3'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="four" value={'4'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="five" value={'5'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="six" value={'6'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="seven" value={'7'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="eight" value={'8'}  />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="nine" value={'9'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="decimal" value={'.'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="equals" value={'='} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="clear" value={'clear'}  />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="add" value={'+'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="subtract" value={'-'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="multiply" value={'*'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="divide" value={'/'} />
            </div>
)

}
```

Display

```
const Display = (props) => {
  return (
            <div>

                <h2 id="display">{props.value} </h2>

            </div>
)};
```

Button

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <input type="button" onClick={props.onClick} id={props.id} value={props.value} />

)

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic appears to be that if there are more than one operator in succession, that you want to remove all operator symbols and retain only the last one.  We can try finding on the following regex pattern:

```
(?:[+/*-])*([+/*-])
```

and then replace with the last captured symbol.

```js
input1 = "1++++1";
input2 = "12*+-3";

input1 = input1.replace(/(?:[+/*-])*([+/*-])/g, "$1");
console.log(input1);
input2 = input2.replace(/(?:[+/*-])*([+/*-])/g, "$1");
console.log(input2);
```